# What is the default character encoding for JAX-RS?

Tags: java, rest, java-ee-7

After some unsuccessfully searching I try good old SO in order to find someone to point me to the right spot of some specification.

I know that I can set the character encoding of some REST call by e.g.:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
```

But if I omit the charset-part, is there a default character encoding defined which a client can assume to be present? And is this specific to either REST in common, JAX-RS in particular or even a special implementation like RESTeasy?

---

sisiphus pointed me to the right place - I wasn't aware that I had to look specifically for JSON since I set this as content type. Nevertheless, one question remains - if no media type is definded, what would then be the default if any?

Comment: If there's no mediatype specified then the server is free to produce whatever character set it wants. This is all a part of content negotiation and how the Accept-* headers work https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec12.html . Character set is just one aspect of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-8.1

JSON defaults to UTF-8. UTF-16 and UTF-32 are also allowed.

Comment: Perfect and quick, thanx!